# How to get an element with jquery that has an illegal character in the id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A third-party control creates an element with an id that looks like:

```
 aspxgv_1803_0_cell1_9_Attribute1^ubd
```

I need to get the value of this element but jquery seems to have issues with the illegal "^" in the id.

```
 var fieldId = 'aspxgv_1803_0_cell1_9_Attribute1^ubd';
 var fieldValue = $('#' + fieldId).val();  // <-------- function stops
```

How can I get the value of this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a jQuery object of a DOM element you can always just pass the element to the $ function rather than a selector.

```
var fieldId = 'aspxgv_1803_0_cell1_9_Attribute1^ubd';
var fieldValue = $(document.getElementById(fieldId)).val();
```

Here's an example using this code to return the html of the jQuery object. http://jsfiddle.net/AZgwm/

Comment: +1, Good suggestion, he can also get the value using value property `document.getElementById(fieldId).value` which is faster than using jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I figured keeping it a jQuery object might be better for whatever else he was doing. I like your escape solution better anyway, it's more elegant. I didn't know jQuery could do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the character.

```
var fieldValue = $('#aspxgv_1803_0_cell1_9_Attribute1\\^ubd').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82AFA/

Comment: This worked for me so +1.  Marking Nimphious the answer cause his worked for me as well and fits a little cleaner in my codebase.

Comment: @SailingJudo You made a good decision, in case that you get the `id` dynamically that will work better.

Comment: Yes, I do. Although your solution works fine when I get the id dynamically as well.  I just added a .replace('^', '\\^') to the end of the variable when I was testing. Still, both good solutions.

Comment: I suppose the one advantage of using the other method is that you won't have to escape every special character.